# Why i cant populate the chef's document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have 3 collections: recipe, chef, and food category.
Im trying to populate the chef collection, and I cant; what is the problem?

```
const recipeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    chef: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Chef',
        required: true
    },
    foodCategory: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'FoodCategory',
        required: true
    },
})

const recipes = await Recipe.find({ chef: '608ed57e58e54d4b9486dae4' })
            .select("-__v")
            .sort({ name: 1 })
            .populate("Chef", 'name status filePath');
```

Comment: You're trying to populate `Chef` not `chef`, fix the typo

Comment: It doesn't work, my friend.

Comment: could you try `const recipes = await Recipe.find({ chef: '608ed57e58e54d4b9486dae4' }).select("-__v").sort({ name: 1 }).populate({path: "chef"});` and `console.log(recipes)`

Comment: OMG, you are my saver!
What was the problem?

Comment: It's the typo you had  `.populate("Chef")` not `chef` I only fixed that and the syntax change was because of my linter. by the way you specify your selection like this `.populate({path: "chef", select: 'name status filePath'});`